# i need to change color of Select i am using React-Select

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I need to change the select box-shadow color,
only need to change selected background-color drop-down list color,
and hover color I am using this CSS is not working properly how can I change the drop-down selected text
CSS part

```
.Select-c {  
  color: black;
}

.Select-c:hover {
  color: #0bb7a7; 
}

.Select-c ,
.Select-c:active {
    box-shadow: green!important;
    border-color: red!important;
    color: black;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Code

```
<Col>
  <label
    style={{ width: "120%", fontWeight: "600" }}
    for="usertype"
  >
  <header style={{ fontWeight: "600" }}>
      Select Search Type
  </header>
   </label>
    <Select
    className="Select-c"
    options={FormType}
    styles={styles}
    name="FormType"
    onChange={handleIndividualChange}
    placeholder="Select Type"
   ></Select>
</Col>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the theme.
https://react-select.com/styles#overriding-the-theme

```
<Select
    className="Select-c"
    options={FormType}
    styles={styles}
    name="FormType"
    onChange={handleIndividualChange}
    placeholder="Select Type"
    theme={(theme) => ({
      ...theme,
      colors: {
        ...theme.colors,
        text: 'blue',
        primary25: 'pink',
        primary: 'black',
      },
    })}
  />
```